# How to Convert MUI X date range picker dates to a specific format?

Tags: reactjs, datetime, material-ui, datepicker, date-formatting

I am using MUI X Date Range Picker Component: [Link to MUI X](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/date-range-picker/)

The format of date which is getting stored is as printed on the console log screen of the browser: [image: Date Format]

Tried to use the `format()` method of  `date-fns` `npm` package to convert the date format but it is not working.

***Question 1: What package/method should I use to convert the date to regular 'dd/MM/yyyy' format ?***

***Question 2: How to subtract the number of days between them for future calculation? (Code snippet would be really helpful)***

I am a new student of react & material UI. Please help me as I am not able to figure it out.

Comment: I am also looking for proper solution. currently I have pulled date from `$d` and used with `moment` library like  `moment(myDate.$d).format(dd/MM/yyyy)`

Comment: we are getting a similar problem, did you finally figure it it out?